# Android parse JSON, how to fetch only single parameter

Tags: android, json

hi i have only one parameter to parse

this is what i have tried....

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
```

and here is the below json

```
{"result" : "169489465811879423"}
```

Comment: Result is not an Array, as you are trying to parse it as, otherwise you would see [ ] brackets in the json string.

Comment: it's not related but more an advice : une Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to parse your json and in general reflect you api in an Interface

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
```

Here there is no JsonArray and you are trying to get an array